# How to setup a python code with click with commands with setup.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, click, setup.py

I want to be able to install some python code, using python-click and commands, with `setup.py`. I have the following complete code:

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.option(
    "-v",
    "--verbose",
    count=True,
    default=0,
    help="-v for DEBUG",
)
def cli(verbose):
    print(verbose)

@cli.command("list")
@click.option(
    "--option1"
)
def my_list_command(option1):
    print(option1)


@cli.command("find")
@click.option(
    "--option2"
)
def my_find_command(option2):
     print(option2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   cli()
```

which defines two commands `list` and `find`. When I save that file as `mycode.py` I can do for example

```
python mycode.py list --option1 opt1
python mycode.py find --option2 opt2
```

and the code works as expected, i.e. I have two commands with their options.

But when I now try to install this code with `setup.py` as follows

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='MyCode',
    install_requires=[
        'click',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mytest=mycode.cli'
        ],
    },
)
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: For req: MyCode==0.0.1. Invalid script entry point: <ExportEntry mytest = mycode.cli:None []> - A callable suffix is required. Cf https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/#use-for-scripts for more information.
```

How to properly setup a multi-command python-click code, so I can use it like the above examples?

Comment: it should be mycode:cli, but your setup.py is also incomplete

Comment: look into typer - https://typer.tiangolo.com/ . Very intuitive and easy to code.

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there, just change `mycode.cli` to `mycode:cli`.

When specifying entry points, the module path is separated with `.`, while the function to be called by the entry points comes afterward, prefixed with a `:`, for example `package.module:function`.

For more information see [the docs](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point).

Answer (score -2):

This is an operator issue.

When calling a module from a package, `.` is used. whereas,

for calling the function from the specific module, `:` is used.

Check out [Python-Packaging](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point) documentation.